# Highcharts bubble chart datalabels color contrast issue

Tags: javascript, highcharts

Recently I updated highcharts version from v8.2.2 to v9.1.0. After this migration I noticed that highcharts doesn't draw  bubble chart datalabels like before and the contrast of labels is not satisfactory anymore.

here is an image of v8.2.2 which the datalabels are ok. as you see the contrast of datalabels are good. even highcharts added outlines and borders to text for better presentation.

[image]

here is an image of v9.1.0 in which without any change in code, and just by updating, the datalabels are not showing well.

[image]

**how can I achieve previous datalebs design in v9.1.0?**

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Solved this issue.
just add these two properties to **plotOptions.bubble.dataLabels.style** OR **plotOptions.series.dataLabels.style** and it works.

```
color: 'contrast',
textOutline: 'none'
```

my complete plotOptions object:

```
plotOptions: {
  bubble: {
    minSize: '1%',
    maxSize: '20%',
    dataLabels : {
      style: {
        color: 'contrast',
        textOutline: 'none'
      }
    }
  },
  series: {
    dataLabels: {
      enabled: true,
      format: '{point.name}',
      
    },
    animation: false
  }
},
```